# How can I make header cart dropdown menu fullscreen at mobile?

Tags: css

I want to make my header cart dropdown menu fullscreen at mobile version of my website. I tried some css codes but it is not responsive at all mobile screens. Any idea how can I fit it to content responsively?

```
#cart .dropdown-menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px !important;
    width: 460px;
    height: 750px;
    right: -69px;
    list-style: none none;
    border: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 17px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 18px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 7%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 18px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 7%);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Set width: 100%;

Comment: Hey @Grumpy I tried but something is affecting to it. When I set it to 100% it gets so narrow. I cant find the code with inspector. I dont know what it cause.

Answer (score 0):

what i think you should try is:

```
#cart .dropdown-menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px !important;
    width: 100%;<--------------
    height: 100%; <------------
    right: -69px;
    list-style: none none;
    border: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 17px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 18px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 7%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 18px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 7%);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hello @mustache,

I tried but 

when I add 

display: inline-block; 

menu becomes unclickable

when I add width and height 100% it gets narrow :/